# 3 Dependent selection boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 exactly the same selection boxes generated by PHP code.
I want to disable each selected option on the other selection boxes.

I've found this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672636/1523400) and using it's [2nd edit fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RaBuQ/5/) there I've almost got what I need in this section:

```
sel.nextAll().each(function(){
        if(prev){
            $(this).find("[value='" + prev+ "']").prop("disabled",false);
        }
        $(this).find("[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled",true);
    });
```

Thing is, that the selection disable affect only the following selection boxes and not backwards, meaning: when selecting option in the 3rd (most right) selection box, it is not disabled on the other selection boxes.
I tried using prevAll combining the the nextAll but with not much of success.

Any idea how could I reach this kind of behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your html. The jquery you're using may not be suitable for your purpose. I mean that it probably can be done easier...

Comment: My HTML is pretty much the same as in the given example, 3 exactly the same selection boxes, the options just generated by PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a new code under `nextAll` side.

```
sel.nextAll()....
...

sel.prevAll().each(function(){
    if(prev){
        $(this).find("[value='" + prev+ "']").prop("disabled",false);
    }
    $(this).find("[value='" + val + "']").prop("disabled",true);
});
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/RaBuQ/160/

When select something from 3rd selectbox, will disable options from another selectboxes.

Comment: That will do it, I've tried it myself already and for some reason didn't got the result you are having here.
Thank you.